# How To Uninstall Jupyter from Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, uninstallation

Newbie on Ubuntu here.
So I trying to uninstall Jupyter but whenever I type the Jupyter command on terminal it is showing this

```
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
               [--paths] [--json]
               [subcommand]
jupyter: error: one of the arguments --version subcommand --config-dir --data-dir --runtime-dir --paths is required
```

I tried searching the answer here and even tried using pip3 , pip
The result were as follows :

```
pip3 uninstall jupyter_core

Found existing installation: jupyter-core 4.6.3
Not uninstalling jupyter-core at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'jupyter-core'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

```
pip3 uninstall jupyter
WARNING: Skipping jupyter as it is not installed
```

I used this command as well

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip uninstall jupyter_core jupyter_qtconsole nbformat nbconvert notebook
```

The Result showing was this

```
Found existing installation: jupyter-core 4.6.3
Not uninstalling jupyter-core at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'jupyter-core'. No files were found to uninstall.
WARNING: Skipping jupyter-qtconsole as it is not installed.
Found existing installation: nbformat 5.0.4
Not uninstalling nbformat at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'nbformat'. No files were found to uninstall.
Found existing installation: nbconvert 5.6.1
Not uninstalling nbconvert at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'nbconvert'. No files were found to uninstall.
Found existing installation: notebook 6.0.3
Not uninstalling notebook at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'notebook'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

What is the solution for this?
If anyone can help , it would be great.

Comment: Do you remember how you installed it? Did you try `sudo pip3 uninstall jupyter_core`?

Comment: @Tomer I just used ```sudo apt install jupyter``` and ```sudo apt install jupyter_core``` I tried your command it was showing this ```Found existing installation: jupyter-core 4.6.3
Not uninstalling jupyter-core at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'jupyter-core'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Comment: Then you need to uninstall it with apt. Try `sudo apt uninstall jupyter jupyter_core`

Comment: @Tomer Not happening, says can't locate Jupyter Core